# Clear line in the Python IDLE shell

Tags: python, shell, python-idle

Is there a keyboard shortcut to clear a line for the Python IDLE shell? I know <kbd>Ctrl-K</kbd> works if you are at the beginning of a line, but is there a shortcut to do it when you are at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set idle's `Key Set` to `IDLE Classic Unix` (`Options -> Configure -> Use a Built-in Key Set -> IDLE Classic Unix`) you'll at least be able to get the same effect with `C-a C-k`. There doesn't seem to be anything that resembles `C-u` in Emacs, for example.

You could look into [`EditorWindow.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/cde4b66699fe/Lib/idlelib/EditorWindow.py#l204) and [`configHandler.py`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/cde4b66699fe/Lib/idlelib/configHandler.py#l551) if you're willing to add the functionality yourself (though it seems that `C-k` is a default binding in tk's editor widget).