# Printing progress of a loop - IDLE vs. Terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7

I wrote a script where at some point I want to print 
the progress of a loop. 
Instead of printing it line by line I want the current
line to be overwritten in each iteration. 
The problem is, if I execute my script from terminal it works fine, but if I run the script in IDLE it prints the progress always in a
new line.

It is just out of curiosity and I would like to understand why the two
behave different.

Here is a reduced example of code:

```
import time
import sys

max_iter = range(5)

for i in max_iter:

    prog = (i + 1) / float(len(max_iter))
    sys.stdout.write("\r {}%".format( prog * 100 ) )
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: that's because terminals are different. IDLE terminal is unable to "rewind" the line.

Comment: Ok and ILDE can't do that in general; also not with a different solution?

Comment: if you want, you can use the `%` operator to print not ever item, but say, every 10%. So you still have an idea of progress, without overloading the terminal.

Comment: Have a look at [tqdm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm) that's a great library for progess bars!

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096329/clear-line-in-the-python-idle-shell?